# Passing Multiple Attributes to hover_data as a dictionary in dash plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot a line chart of the air quality data with respect to time. I want to show multiple attributes when user hover over the graph in the dictionary. Right now in `hover_data` i am just only passing `Date` and its format like `"|%Y-%m-%d"` i want to show another attribute that is stored in my dataframe as objectID , how can i pass another attribute to the dictionary like ObjectID to my `hover_data` Dictionary.

Below is my code snippet:

```
df =pd.read_csv('.../path to my Data/Merged_Bins_Both_Sep_Aug.csv')
column= [df.AI, df.CO, df.SO2, df.NO2, df.O3]
fig = px.line(df, x="Date", y=column, hover_data={"Date": "|%Y-%m-%d"}, title='Sentinal 5-P Air Quality Time Series Analysis') 
fig.update_xaxes( dtick="M1", tickformat="%d\n%Y")
```

below is the screenshot of my output i want to show ObjectID (present in my dataframe) as well in this hover_data . Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you can do something like this:

```
hover_data={"Date": "|%d-%m-%Y", "ObjectID": True}
```

This adds the `ObjectID` column to the `hover_data` with default formatting ([source](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/)).

Comment: Thank you so much its working, i was actually confused about how can dictionary would know that Dataframe would have "ObjectID" column and we were assigning boolean variable to that column in dictionary.

Comment: and moreover the Date in hover still showing nan-nan-nan despite after editing the date format with your recommendation

Comment: The nan part is not due to the formatter, but your data. You would have to share your data (`df`) or a sample in the question so that part is reproducible. You can paste the output of `df.to_dict()` in the question for a nice reproducible output of your dataframe.

Comment: I also made "Date": True and it is picking Date from data correctly. and nan does not reproduced. But, yes i have compromised on format of Date.